# XML REGEX to find characters 40 to X

Tags: xml, regex

I have the string

```
TEXAS RANGERS ASSOCIATION               PARKING ATTENDANT
```

I need to get the characters from position 40 to the end of the line. It has to be XML compatible due to limitations with my software.

I also have a string

```
STAFF WRITER                             XXX      NNATIONAL   SPORTS EDITOR
```

I need to get all characters after but not including `XXX      N`. Again using XML compatible REGEX.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as XML compatible REGEX.  XML isn't a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question:

```
/^.{40}(.*)/    # group \1 contains "PARKING ATTENDANT"
```

For the second:

```
/XXX\s+N(.*)/   # group \1 contains "NATIONAL SPORTS EDITOR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by xml compatibale, but this regex should capture all the charaters from the 40th to the end: `(^.{40})(.*$)`. The second group will be what you need.